# Devise registration confirmation wacky

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

[image]

That is how devise is sending the registration confirmation: `subjectConfirmation instructions` is strange. Why is the subject wacky and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick Robertson got me going in the right direction. The change I made to my local file is below and it fixed the strange out put but it's probably not the best solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have a problem with the I18n file.  He's a sample configuration for English in terms of the confirmation mailer:

```
#config/locales/en.yaml
en:
  devise:
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        user_subject: "[AWESOME POSSUM] Please Confirm Your Registration"
        admin_subject: "[A-P] Please Confirm Your Administrative Account"
        subject: "[AWESOME POSSUM] New Registration Confirmation"
```

This provides specific subject for User and Admin devise resources, and has a default scope of subject for any other resource.

Comment: Thanks, you got me in the right direction. It looks like you got a better solution but it didn't work for me.